# Why is my backtrace being filtered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm experiencing an exception in a third-party library. For some reason the backtrace skips a lot of lines. I've put this in an initializer:

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_filters!
```

These lines have no effect.

What else could affect the contents of the backtrace? Is there a global object I can inspect, or a method invocation I can search for in suspicious gems?

I'm using JRuby, Rails 4.1, and the library in question is [dullard](https://github.com/thirtyseven/dullard).

**further explanation**

here's an example of how backtraces normally work. This code...

```
def a
  raise "i am in a"
end

def b
  puts "i am in b"
  a
end

def c
  puts "i am in c"
  b
end

c
```

results in this output...

```
➔ ruby exceptiontest.rb
i am in c
i am in b
exceptiontest.rb:2:in `a': i am in a (RuntimeError)
    from exceptiontest.rb:7:in `b'
    from exceptiontest.rb:12:in `c'
    from exceptiontest.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

with my problem, I am instead getting this output...

```
➔ ruby exceptiontest.rb
i am in c
i am in b
exceptiontest.rb:2:in `a': i am in a (RuntimeError)
    from exceptiontest.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I assume you have restarted your server after adding those lines?

Comment: Yes. [i need more characters for this message...]

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this occurring in production?
2. Can you provide more context regarding the backtrace?  By skipping lines, you mean that some of the backtrace is actually visible, but some is not?
3. If development, do you know which gem is raising the exception?  If so, open it (bundle open ) and, using `pry`, put a `binding.pry` statement immediately preceding the line of interest from the backtrace. You will be able to see what is going on at the time of the exception and you will be able to `cd` into further context if necessary.

Comment: 1. it's occurring in development 2. the exception happens when `Foo.bar` is invoked, but the stack trace does not show the invocation of `Foo.bar`, it only shows the invocation of previous code 3. I have done that in order to work forward from the code shown previous to the exception in order to find the real source -- is that what you mean?

Comment: see "further explanation" above